Aws amplify gen 2 - Listen to forget password event Hosted UI
Is there any way to listen to the forget password event in gen 2 amplify? It's causing a weird infinite loop in my code because I have no listener for the action that just happened. I'm using signInWithRedirect with Cognito Hosted UI.
I'm using React 18.2.0 and aws-amplify 6.5.3.
   Hub.listen('auth', async ({ payload }) => {
  switch (payload.event) {
    case 'signedIn':
      break;
    case 'signedOut':
    case 'tokenRefresh_failure':
    case 'signInWithRedirect_failure':
      break;
    case 'forgotPassword':
      //How to capture this?
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

